# Cron jobs running, but not executing / in a frozen state

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron

I have never seen this problem before, and I am pretty confused. I have 3 cron jobs that execute PHP code through CakePHP's console system. All 3 jobs have been running for months with no problems, and continue to run. The weird problem is that the output from these cron jobs is always the same thing, yet when I run the code manually it is the correct updated output. I log the output of each job into txt files, so that I can review the timestamps and outputs.

Here is the output of one of the jobs from the txt file (that ran July 5th 12:30):

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.1.2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/html/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------

- Calculating stats
- 79 players calculated

---------------------------------------------------------------

CalculateStats complete!
Shell took 9.4434700012207 seconds
```

And here is the output when I run the shell manually:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.1.2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/html/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------

- Calculating stats
- 188 players calculated

---------------------------------------------------------------

CalculateStats complete!
Shell took 6.4958961009979 seconds
```

When the job runs again (every 4 hours), the output will be the same as the 1st example. It's as if the job is stuck in a frozen state and I am not too sure how to fix it.

I've disabled caching, checked PATH and made sure there is a trailing newline in the crontab. All jobs (and myself) are also ran as the root user. For reference, here is my crontab.

```
0 0-23/4 * * * /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /var/www/html/app/ calculate_stats > /root/calculate_stats.txt

30 0-23/4 * * * /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /var/www/html/app/ aggregate_votes > /root/aggregate_votes.txt

0 15 * * 3 /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /var/www/html/app/ game_sprint_reset > /root/game_sprint_reset.txt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Long shot, but maybe put the command in double quotes: `0-23/4 * * * "/var/www/html/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /var/www/html/app/ calculate_stats" > /root/calculate_stats.txt`

Comment: @BenAshton: Unlikely to help; it will make cron try to execute a command called `"/var/www/html/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /var/www/html/app/ calculate_stats"` rather than passing arguments to `.../cake`

Comment: Are you sure the output files are being written each time? Check their timestamps (`ls -l`).

Comment: Perhaps your code relies on an IP address being present somewhere? If you ran the code via cronjob, it wouldn't work properly in most cases.

Comment: Yeah, the timestamps are correct.

    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  573 Jul  5 16:30 aggregate_votes.txt
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  563 Jul  5 16:00 calculate_stats.txt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  731 Jul  4 15:00 game_sprint_reset.txt

As you can see, the crons are running. I'll mess around with them a bit more.

Comment: So the problem seemed to correct itself, not sure how or why. I will monitor it to see if it happens again.